# Server.URLEncode started to replace blank with plus ("+") instead of percent-20 ("%20")

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, urlencode

Given this piece of code:

```
<%
    Response.Write Server.URLEncode("a doc file.asp")
%>
```

It output this for a while (like Javascript call `encodeURI`):

```
a%20doc%20file.asp
```

Now, for unknow reason, I get:

```
a+doc+file%2Easp
```

I'm not sure of what I touched to make this happen (maybe the file content encoding ANSI/UTF-8). Why did this happen and how can I get the first behavior of `Server.URLEncode`, ie using a percent encoding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classic ASP hasn't been updated in nearly 20 years, so `Server.URLEncode` still uses the [RFC-1866](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866) standard, which specifies spaces be encoded as `+` symbols (which is a hangover from an old `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` media type), you must be mistaken in thinking it was encoding spaces as `%20` at some point, not unless there's an IIS setting you can change that I'm unaware of.

More modern languages use the [RFC-3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) standard for encoding URLs, which is why Javascript's `encodeURI` function returns spaces encoded as `%20`.

Both `+` and `%20` should be treated exactly the same when decoded by any browser thanks to RFC backwards compatibility, but it's generally considered best to use `%20` when encoding spaces in a URL as it's the more modern standard now, and some decoding functions (such as Javascript's `decodeURIComponent`) won't recognise `+` symbols as spaces and will fail to properly decode URLs that use them over `%20`.

You can always use a custom function to encode spaces as `%20`:

```
function URL_encode(ByVal url)
    
    url = Server.URLEncode(url)
    url = replace(url,"+","%20")
    
    URL_encode = url
    
end function
```

Comment: I think it was indeed a mistake. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I think I had an issue with a .NET component finally. I used `Web.HttpUtility.urlencode` instead of `Uri.EscapeUriString`, which is [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517586) for this case.